# Select count of timestamp formatted field in short date format to give number of rows

Tags: sql-server, select, date, timestamp

I have a field titled DTUpdated and it is a timestamp field.

I am trying to select a count of the dates in the rows that are xx old. i.e. 0-3 months, 3-6 months etc.

I am not at the writing date selection criteria for the selection yet as i am stuck getting the first part of the query to simply count the occurrences of each day in a results pane.

The query i have so far is as follows but it is not grouping the data by the days as returned.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[SCAData].[dbo].[Camera].[DTUpdated],105) AS Date_Updated,
COUNT(DTUpdated) AS No_of_Rows 
FROM [SCAData].[dbo].[Camera]
GROUP BY DTUpdated  
ORDER BY DTUpdated;
```

Result:

```
Date_Updated    No_of_Rows
03-10-2006      1
03-10-2006      1
05-10-2006      1
05-10-2006      1
05-10-2006      1
05-10-2006      1
05-10-2006      1
05-10-2006      1
05-10-2006      1
06-10-2006      1
06-10-2006      1
06-10-2006      1
06-10-2006      1
06-10-2006      1
```

Can someone please help or also suggest how to then get these back based on date selections of last 3 months, 3-6 months?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what database are you using? SQL Server? postgres? Oracle? mysql? other? and what version

Comment: I am using SQL Management Studio.

Comment: I have since managed to get this far to select count by day and country (constabulary)

Comment: SELECT 
  Convert(char(10), DTUpdated, 105) AS Date_Updated,
  count(distinct ID) AS Row_Count,
  Constabulary
FROM Camera
GROUP BY Convert(char(10), DTUpdated, 105),Constabulary
ORDER BY Date_Updated ASC

Comment: I have also now changed the date format to 103 so it is now DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: Can you post the result of this query please? SELECT @@VERSION

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, it cannot be a timestamp, because timestamp is an hexadecimal integer. So either you are using another database than SQL, either it's not a timestamp column. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format/8119407)

Comment: Hi. This is on MS SQL Server and i have just checked the properties of the column and it is in fact a datetime field.

Comment: The version is as follows: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) 
 Apr 29 2016 23:23:58 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: That makes sense :-) I wrote you a query to do what you are trying to do. I would go with the "DATE" format instead of VARCHAR. Maybe you should change the title since it's a datetime format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the column type is a datetime and this is SQL Server 2016, converting it to a date is easy :

```
SELECT CONVERT(Date,[SCAData].[dbo].[Camera].[DTUpdated]) AS Date_Updated,
COUNT(DTUpdated) AS No_of_Rows 
FROM [SCAData].[dbo].[Camera]
GROUP BY CONVERT(Date,[SCAData].[dbo].[Camera].[DTUpdated])  
ORDER BY 1;
```

If you really want to do it via an VARCHAR field, just do it like that :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[SCAData].[dbo].[Camera].[DTUpdated],105) AS Date_Updated,
COUNT(DTUpdated) AS No_of_Rows 
FROM [SCAData].[dbo].[Camera]
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[SCAData].[dbo].[Camera].[DTUpdated],105)  
ORDER BY 1;
```